# Neo4J Query with multiple filter does not return the expected result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am using the following Neo4JClient code to query for all the shipment count that is due within a wee, one week to 21 days and greater than 21 days.

```
    var query = GraphClient.Cypher
        .Merge("(user:Person{InternalId:{userId}})")
        .WithParam("userId", userId)
        .With("user")
        .Match("(veh:Vehicle)<-[:HAS_VEHICLE_TYPE]-(load:ActiveShipment)-[:SHIPPED_BY]->(shipper:Shipper), (user)-[:WORKS_FOR_COMPANY]->(transporter:Transporter)")
        .Where("((load.RestrictedBidding = false) OR (user)-[:WORKS_FOR_COMPANY]->(transporter)<-[:HAS_TRANSPORTER]-(shipper)<-[:SHIPPED_BY]-(load))")
        .AndWhere("(load)-[:HAS_VEHICLE_TYPE]->(veh)<-[:HAS_VEHICLE]-(transporter)")
        .With("load, transporter, shipper, user")
        .Match("p=(shipFrom:City)<-[:SHIP_FROM_CITY]-(load)-[:SHIP_TO_CITY]->(shipTo:City)")
        .With("load,  collect(shipFrom) as FromCities, collect(shipTo) as ToCities, COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate <= {withinWeek})) as LessThanWeek , COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and (x.PickupDate > {withinWeek}) and (x.PickupDate <= {within3Week}))) as NextWeekToFortnight, COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate > {within3Week})) as LaterThan3Week")
        .WithParams(new { withinWeek = next7Days, within3Week = next3Weeks })
        .Return((load,FromCities, ToCities, LessThanWeek , NextWeekToFortnight, LaterThan3Week )=>new 
        { 
            OneWeek = Return.As<long>("LessThanWeek"),
            SevenToTwentyOneDays = Return.As<long>("NextWeekToFortnight"),
            Later = Return.As<long>("LaterThan3Week")

        });
```

this generates the following Cypher query

```
MERGE (user:Person{InternalId:2})   
WITH user   
MATCH (veh:Vehicle)<-[:HAS_VEHICLE_TYPE]-(load:ActiveShipment)-[:SHIPPED_BY]->(shipper:Shipper), 
      (user)-[:WORKS_FOR_COMPANY]->(transporter:Transporter)   WHERE ((load.RestrictedBidding = false) OR (user)-[:WORKS_FOR_COMPANY]->(transporter)<-[:HAS_TRANSPORTER]-(shipper)<-[:SHIPPED_BY]-(load))   AND (load)-[:HAS_VEHICLE_TYPE]->(veh)<-[:HAS_VEHICLE]-(transporter)   
WITH load, transporter, shipper, user   
MATCH p=(shipFrom:City)<-[:SHIP_FROM_CITY]-(load)-[:SHIP_TO_CITY]->(shipTo:City)   
WITH load,  collect(shipFrom) as FromCities, collect(shipTo) as ToCities, 
     COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate <= 4/30/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30)) as LessThanWeek , 
     COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and (x.PickupDate > 4/30/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30) and (x.PickupDate <= 5/14/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30))) as NextWeekToFortnight, 
     COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate > 5/14/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30)) as LaterThan3Week   
RETURN LessThanWeek AS OneWeek , NextWeekToFortnight AS SevenToTwentyOneDays , LaterThan3Week AS Later
```

but the results are not what I expect as I am getting OneWeek , SevenToTwentyOneDays & Later  all as 1.

To clarify what I am doing: I am trying to do is first get all the loads based on my selection criteria, and then want to get the counts of these loads based where they stand on the delivery dates and only return the count. SO the WITH is really needed in this query.

Q1: Is this even a valid query to write? and how can I fix it.

Q2: Will the use of filter like above impact my query performance and if yes Is there a simpler way to do this?

**Edit:**
BTW the Cypher query pasted above is from the Debug Text of neo4jClient which means the actual query is parameterized but the debug text is writing out the parameter values for easy understanding so the dates are not written properly.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

Q1: The date/time strings (e.g., "4/30/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30") are not supported by Cypher. I suggest using epoch time (in milliseconds) -- presumably your nodes' date/time properties are using that?

Q2: This is a somewhat simpler (and probably faster) query. You had a lot of duplicated patterns, which have been removed. I was able to come up with a consolidated MATCH pattern. Also, I am proposing the use of parameters `id`, `date1` and `date2`, which will allow the neo4j engine to cache the execution plan and re-use it with every query:

```
MERGE (user:Person{InternalId:{id}})   
WITH user   
MATCH (user)-[:WORKS_FOR_COMPANY]->(transporter:Transporter)-[:HAS_VEHICLE]->(veh:Vehicle)<-[:HAS_VEHICLE_TYPE]-(load:ActiveShipment)-[:SHIPPED_BY]->(shipper:Shipper)
WHERE ((load.RestrictedBidding = false) OR (transporter)<-[:HAS_TRANSPORTER]-(shipper)<-[:SHIPPED_BY]-(load))   
WITH load, transporter, shipper, user   
MATCH p=(shipFrom:City)<-[:SHIP_FROM_CITY]-(load)-[:SHIP_TO_CITY]->(shipTo:City)   
WITH load,  collect(shipFrom) as FromCities, collect(shipTo) as ToCities, 
     COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate <= {date1})) as LessThanWeek , 
     COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and (x.PickupDate > {date1}) and (x.PickupDate <= {date2}))) as NextWeekToFortnight, 
     COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate > {date2})) as LaterThan3Week   
RETURN LessThanWeek AS OneWeek , NextWeekToFortnight AS SevenToTwentyOneDays , LaterThan3Week AS Later;
```

Comment: I am using Neo4JClient, and the query i pasted is the Debug test that it generates. What I mean to say is that I i am already using the parameterized query. As its a debug query, its writing out the parameters in to the Query string which is actually messing up the   Date part. I was more wondering is the `COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate <= {date1})) as LessThanWeek` a valid way to get the data I am looking for, and is there a better way to get that information without overloading the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Filter can reduce the size of a collection, possibly to zero, but it will still be one collection. Counting the collection(s) will return the number of collections, not the number of items in the collection. The number of collections will be the same (1 in your case) no matter what the filter does.

```
WITH [1,2] AS nn
RETURN COUNT (FILTER (n IN nn WHERE n > 0)) AS cnt;
==> +-----+
==> | cnt |
==> +-----+
==> | 1   |
==> +-----+
==> 1 row
==> 20 ms
```

If you change the filter criteria to `n > 1` or `n > 2` it still returns 1, because there is still one collection. If you expect the filter to change the result, you may be want to use `length`.

```
WITH [1,2] AS nn
RETURN LENGTH (FILTER (n IN nn WHERE n > 0)) AS cnt;
==> +-----+
==> | cnt |
==> +-----+
==> | 2   |
==> +-----+
==> 1 row
==> 20 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$
```

I don't quite understand your query so I don't know how to answer the rest. Particularly, a) which node has the date property? and b) Why are you testing for date property on all the nodes in path `p`? You can put sample data in [a console](http://console.neo4j.org) to make it easier to answer.

Comment: Actually my requirement is quit simple, I want to first query for all matching `(load)` nodes and then filter and collect the count of these loads that have `PickupDate` within week, between week and 21 days and later than 21 days. I am unable to understand how to query/filter on the previous query result passed via `WITH`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what I was doing wrong.

This part of my code was incorrect.

```
WITH load,  collect(shipFrom) as FromCities, collect(shipTo) as ToCities, 
     COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate <= 4/30/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30)) as LessThanWeek , 
     COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and (x.PickupDate > 4/30/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30) and (x.PickupDate <= 5/14/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30))) as NextWeekToFortnight, 
     COUNT(filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate > 5/14/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30)) as LaterThan3Week   
RETURN LessThanWeek AS OneWeek , NextWeekToFortnight AS SevenToTwentyOneDays , LaterThan3Week AS Later
```

Instead what I needed was something like this:

```
WITH load,  collect(shipFrom) as FromCities, collect(shipTo) as ToCities, 
     filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate <= 4/30/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30) as LessThanWeek , 
     filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and (x.PickupDate > 4/30/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30) and (x.PickupDate <= 5/14/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30)) as NextWeekToFortnight, 
     filter(x IN Nodes(p) WHERE x:Shipment and x.PickupDate > 5/14/2014 12:00:00 AM +05:30) as LaterThan3Week   
RETURN 
   COUNT( DISTINCT LessThanWeek) AS OneWeek , 
   COUNT( DISTINCT NextWeekToFortnight) AS SevenToTwentyOneDays , 
   COUNT( DISTINCT LaterThan3Week) AS Later
```