# Retry: Neo4j Query on first query result to get insight in to what is returned

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I had asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228470/neo4j-query-with-multiple-filter-does-not-return-the-expected-result/23240699?noredirect=1#23240699) question few days back but maybe as I was not clear as I didn't get much response.

let me try to rephrase my question to something like this:

`I have few customers who are placing the orders with various products. and I am interested in knowing orders placed for various combinations of products and customers then bucket them into the number of orders last week, last fortnight, last month etc`.

I am able to query the orders based on my criteria, but I am unable to understand how to then use this result in to data I need.

lets say my data is like this:

`(c:Customer)<-[:PLACED_BY]-(o:Order)-[:HAS_PRODUCT]->(p:Product), (o)-[:PLACED_ON]->(d:Date)`

and assuming that I have successfully found the `Order`'s I am looking for, then how do I efficiently get the count i want out of these selected orders.

```
{... some queries that returns (o:Order) of interest ...}
With o
RETURN ??? as CountLastWeek, ??? as LastFortnight,  ??? as LastMonth
```

BTW i also have `OrderedDate` property on the `Order` if that helps simplify the query.

is it even possible to achieve this in Cypher?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is date time indexing. This is most certainly possible to achieve with Cypher.

You'll need to index your nodes via relationships. Each date is a day, you need to batch those into groups. Each day has a week that it is in, and a month that it is in. You just need to add in those groups to your dates and then aggregate on the collections of dates belonging to a week, a fort night, or a month.

[image: Multilevel DateTime Index]

Comment: My issue is not as much as how to query this first time, I am more looking for how to chain the query, where I am able to first get the nodes I want and then have another query that works on the result set of first query. Is that possible?